# fastapi how to modularize code into multiple files with access to app decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I want to distribute my FastAPI code into multiple files so as to make it clear for team, so instead of using decorator i tried using APIRoute , but in this way I can't use FastAPI decorator in other file.
Lets say I have my `main.py` like this

```
... import statements

rts = [
    APIRoute("/{value}", methods=["get"], endpoint=read_item)
]

app = FastAPI(routes=rts)

uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

now I have defined `read_item` method in another file named `read_item.py` which i am importing in my main file.

```
def read_item(value: int | float = None):
    results = {"value": value}
    return results
```

if i start using @app decorator in main file , it will become too large.
now the problem is that i can not access app decorators like `@app.on_event` in `read_items.py` file as app is declared in `main` file and method needs to declared in `read_item` file.
is there any way around this in FastAPI ?

Comment: Check out [API routers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter)

Answer (score 6):

The modularization of routes in FastAPI is done using the APIRouter function. APIRouter allows you to create separate instances of the router that can be assembled into a FastAPI application.

Here is an example of how to modularize the routes:

## app/routers/user.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/users/")
async def read_users():
    return [{"username": "Foo"}, {"username": "Bar"}]

@router.get("/users/me")
async def read_user_me():
    return {"username": "fakecurrentuser"}

@router.get("/users/{username}")
async def read_user(username: str):
    return {"username": username}
```

## main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.routers import user

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(user.router)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't help at all if you want to separate multiple endpoints for the same router across multiple files.

Comment: you can nest APIRouter as many levels deep as you want. so just add a 3rd py file to the above answer and in `app/routers/user.py` just `from app/routers/user_something import router as something_router` and in `app/routers/user.py` just add in the router.include_router....`

also i know im very late to the party here